# finding the fraction which is minimal to pi in r

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to output the minimal common fraction `n/d`, where `min <= d <= max <= |(n/d) - pi|`

That is:

`n` is the numerator
`d` is the denominator

And the `min`and `max` are the boundaries, i.e. search over all denominators `d`between `min` and `max`.

- If `d = 1`:     `3/1  <=  pi <= 4/1`,    gives the closest fraction of `3/1`  with a distance of `|3/1 - pi|  = 0.142`

  ...
- If `d = 4`:    `12/4 <= pi <= 13/4`,   gives the closest fraction of `13/4` with a distance of `|13/4 - pi| = 0.108`

  ...
- If `d = 6`:    `18/6 <= pi <= 19/6`,   gives the closest fraction of `19/6` with distance of `|19/6 - pi| = 0.025`
- If `d = 7`:   `21/7 <= pi <= 22/7`, gives the closest fraction of `22/7` with a distance of `|22/7 - pi| = 0.001`

  ...
- If `d = 10`:   `31/10 <= pi <= 32/10` gives the closest fraction of `31/10` with a distance of `|31/10 - pi| = 0.042`

Therefore, here, the best approximation is `22/7` when `d = 7` and where a distance to `pi` is `0.001`

```
min = 1
max = 10

library(Rmpfr)

Const("pi", 3333) # pi correct to 1000 decimal places


1 'mpfr' number of precision  3333   bits 
[1] 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989381
```

Comment: What is the point of `library(Rmpfr)`? Are you trying to solve this problem with enormously large integers? In any event, what did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: The `library(Rmpfr)` just allowed me to print `pi` to some number of decimals, base R just printed `pi` as `3.141593`. I am not concerned with the size of the integers, it can be , `10` integers, `50`, `100` etc.

Comment: For base R you can use `format(pi,digits = 16)` (though you won't get any more accuracy than that with a 64-bit number)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that.

Comment: Expansion on JohnColeman's comment: the way the data is *represented* on the console is often different from how it is stored. For instance, if you don't touch `options(digits=...)`, then if you do `pi - 3.141593` then you will most certainly not get 0. This bleeds over into other types, such as: `integer` is printed as a number, the only way to know is if it shows decimal (it isn't int) or do `class(x)` for `integer`; a `data.frame` with either `factor`s or `character`s, they will look the same initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function finds the best approximation in an entire range of denominators (and replaces an extremely inefficient function I posted earlier. Look at the edit history if you want a good laugh).

```
findBestApprox <- function(minD, maxD) {
  lowers <- floor(pi*(minD:maxD))/(minD:maxD)
  i <- which.min(abs(pi - lowers))
  best.lower <- lowers[i]
  uppers <- ceiling(pi*(minD:maxD))/(minD:maxD)
  j <- which.min(abs(pi - uppers))
  best.upper <- uppers[j]
  if(abs(pi - best.lower) < abs(pi - best.upper)) {
    d <- minD + i - 1
    n <- floor(pi*d)
  } else {
    d <- minD + j - 1
    n <- ceiling(pi*d)
  }
  c(n,d)
}
```

For example

```
> findBestApprox(2,1000)
[1] 355 113
> 355/113
[1] 3.141593
```

The vectorized nature of the code makes it very fast, taking only a second or so to search out to 10 million:

```
> findBestApprox(2,10000000)
[1] 5419351 1725033
> format(5419351/1725033,digits = 16)
[1] "3.141592653589815"
> 5419351/1725033 - pi
[1] 2.220446e-14
```